# How to run background procedure in Razor Pages using Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, razor

I've created a web application using asp.net core razor pages.

I'm trying to execute a procedure using javascript without a full postback when I click a button.

This is the code for the button:

```
<input type="submit" value="Complete" class="btn btn-success btn-block" style="Width:100%" onclick="CompleteProcess(@ProcessListReturn.DetailID)"  id="ProcessCompBtn-@ProcessListReturn.DetailID" />
```

Then runs the following Javascript:

```
        function CompleteProcess(WSID) {
        
        var x = 'ProcessComp-' + WSID;
        var y = 'ProcessCompBtn-' + WSID;
        document.getElementById(x).innerText = 'Completed';
        document.getElementById(y).classList = 'btn btn-default  btn-block disabled';
        document.getElementById(x).style.visibility = '';

        $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
            url: '/Workstations/WSProcess?handler=SaveTransaction'

        });
        alert('Javascript executed')
    }
```

I would like it to run the below procedure when the ajax call is sent:

```
        public void OnPostSaveTransaction()
    {
        int InspStage = Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Session.GetString("sesInspStage"));
    }
```

When I click the button it runs the javascript successfully but it comes up with a 400 error when opening the url when I look at the network traffic using "F12" debugger and it doesn't reach the break point of "OnPostSaveTransaction".

What am I doing wrong please.

Many thanks

Comment: Can you try onclick event like this  onclick="CompleteProcess('@ProcessListReturn.DetailID')"

Comment: Hi Sadullah, apologies the onclick side works successfully. It's when it runs the URL, it doesn't reach the breakpoint of SaveTransaction and gives a 400 error looking at the network traffic.

Answer (score 0):

Razor Pages are designed to be protected from (CSRF/XSRF) attacks,so Antiforgery token generation and validation are automatically included in Razor Pages. If you want to use post request with ajax in razor page,you need to add antiforgery token:

html:

```
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
<input type="submit" value="Complete" class="btn btn-success btn-block" style="Width:100%" onclick="CompleteProcess(@ProcessListReturn.DetailID)"  id="ProcessCompBtn-@ProcessListReturn.DetailID" />
```

js:

```
function CompleteProcess(WSID) {
        
        var x = 'ProcessComp-' + WSID;
        var y = 'ProcessCompBtn-' + WSID;
        document.getElementById(x).innerText = 'Completed';
        document.getElementById(y).classList = 'btn btn-default  btn-block disabled';
        document.getElementById(x).style.visibility = '';

        $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
            url: '/Workstations/WSProcess?handler=SaveTransaction',
            headers: { "RequestVerificationToken": $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val() },
        });
        alert('Javascript executed')
    }
```